# How can I retrieve lat and lon rasters of a Geotiff or NetCDF image?

Tags: raster, latitude-longitude, netcdf

[image]

I am working with Landsat 8 and MODIS images for obtain Chlorophyll concentration

I processed Landsat images with ERDAS and get the chlorophyll concentration, (the product was a GeoTIFF image), I want to compare the information obtained with MODIS images in MatLab, for this I had to convert the GeoTIFF to NetCDF format with ArcGIS, but this did not work, because I need the raster of Lat, other raster of Lon and one raster of Chlorophyll in the same file.

I don't know how I can obtain these rasters.

Can you help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate task is to convert geotiff to netcdf then try either of the following methods 
1. Use the Arcgis tool 'raster to netcdf' (easiest way if you have license)
2. Use gdal_translate
3. Code it in python using gdal and scipy

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMap, convert your chlorophyll raster to a point file using something like "Conversion Tools"-> "From Raster"-> "Raster to Point" which takes an input raster and a field (just use your chlorophyll raster's VALUE for the field). Then add two fields to the output feature class or shapefile for LAT and LONG (field type float or double) and Calculate Geometry on the 2 new fields by right-clicking the new fields and selecting "Calculate Geometry". You will choose decimal degrees as the units and calculate LAT to the y and LONG to the X value.

Then if you really need those rasters back you could use "Conversion Tools"-> "To Raster"-> "Point to Raster" to create your LAT and LON rasters.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the raster of Lat and Long in ERDAS, go to Erdas modeller, select "Data Generation" from menu and select "MAP X" and "MAP Y" to generate long and lat rasters respectively.